# Polymer grid in different views

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask because I dont have any code to show.  I'm actually looking for ideas on possible ways to solve my problem.

I have an app that displays the grid on the screen when the media query has a min width of a tablet.

[image]

But when the view is in mobile mode I don't want to show the grid.  Instead I have a drop down menu which has a grid option.  When selected will be show in a paper-dialog (pop up)

[image]

The problem is I have to create two grids (vaadin-grid) and show the appropriate one based on the view.  Is there a way to have only one grid?  Can I put it in a paper-dialog but not pop-out when in tablet and desktop view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An idea I have is use dom-if.  But can an element have the same id if they are in two different id's?  ex  if="mobile" <grid id="gridResult"  if="tablet" <grid id="gridResult" ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your grid element has every custom property then that is an element in the DOM, so you can move it into the dialog if thats needed using javascript:

```js
let myGrid = this.$$('#myGrid');
let myDialogContent = this.$$('#myDialogContent');
Polymer.dom(myDialogContent).appendChild(myGrid);
```

Also if you think it a different way, then you can hide the grid outside of the screen and you can slide that in when it's needed like a drawer panel and you dont need to move the element at all in the DOM.

By the way for programming question stackoverflow has the https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ site, but I think it is Ok to send it here.

Comment: Thanks that some great ideas.  One idea I have above.  Can I use a dom-if with the same element having the same id?  I especially like appending the child

Comment: @adviner I dont have experience in this but if only one dom-if gona add the id to the DOM I think it should not affect to the result, because the <template is="dom-*"> is some sort of Shadow DOM thing which can be empty :)

Comment: I just tried it and it did work.  I do appreciate your input